# Firebase notifications not showing up IOS but the message shows on console

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem while using Firebase push notifications on IOS devices. I send the message from the firebase console and i get it on the log but it is not showing any notification on the devices ive tried.

I have been searching around for posts with similar problems and i have tried everything i have found but it is still not working.

I created the project on firebase, downloaded the google service info file and placed it on the root of the project, turned notifications on on xcode, set priority of messages on high and did a couple of changes.

I also added both 'Firebase/Core' and 'Firebase/Messaging' to the podfile.

Right now i am using the example that Firebase provides you. This is my code.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

// Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
// show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
// [START register_for_notifications]
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: {_, _ in })

  // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
  FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
  UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

// [END register_for_notifications]

FIRApp.configure()

// [START add_token_refresh_observer]
// Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
    name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
    object: nil)
// [END add_token_refresh_observer]

return true
  }

  // [START receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
               fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
  // [END receive_message]

  // [START refresh_token]
  func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
  print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
}

// Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
connectToFcm()
  }
  // [END refresh_token]

  // [START connect_to_fcm]
  func connectToFcm() {
// Won't connect since there is no token
guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
  return;
}

// Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
  if error != nil {
    print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
  } else {
    print("Connected to FCM.")
  }
}
  }
  // [END connect_to_fcm]

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
  // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
  // the InstanceID token.
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

// With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
 FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
  }

  // [START connect_on_active]
  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
connectToFcm()
  }
  // [END connect_on_active]

  // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
// FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
// print("Disconnected from FCM.")
  }
  // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                          willPresent notification: UNNotification,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)
// Change this to your preferred presentation option
completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])

  }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                          didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                          withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

completionHandler()
  }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
  // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
print(remoteMessage.appData)
}
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

Comment: Did you uploaded the APNs certificates in Firebase as well?

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention that, i just redid everything and still no luck. I am trying it on an ipad, does that make any difference?

Comment: Check out this blog post for a whole slew of solutions: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html

Comment: same issue messages are receiving in console but not showing.

Comment: Has any one gotten solution for this?

Comment: While app is running foreground, you will receive message, applicationReceivedRemoteMessage gets called but system won't show an alert.You need to show custom alert here in applicationReceivedRemoteMessage method.

Answer (score 1):

The app needs to be in the background in order for it to show.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52683855/4833705) to make sure everything is set up correctly.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52687669/4833705) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685262/4833705) and this [answer](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1339#issuecomment-399904389) and this is what got it to work for me.

> However, there is simple workaround for this - looks like you have to
>   set the messaging delegate (Messaging.messaging().delegate = ...)
>   before FirebaseApp.configure()

Meaning:

```
// add this first
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

// add this second
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

and:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

and this

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Your Firebase FCM Registration Token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
}
```