# iOS Firebase Cloud Messaging Notifications not being received after using .p8 file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed all the steps below and added the appropriate imports and code in `App Delegate`. I also made sure I allowed Notifications to be accepted when I ran the app.

**Following the steps below, why is it that I can't receive the Notifications after I send one from the Firebase Cloud Messaging Console ?**

1. In my Developer account I went to `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`
2. Under `Keys`, I selected `All` and clicked the Add button (+) in the upper-right corner
3. Under `Key Description`, I entered a unique name for the signing key
4. Under `Key Services`, I selected the `APNs` checkbox, then clicked `Continue` then clicked `Confirm`
5. I copied the `Key ID` (used in step 7) and clicked `Download` to generate and download the `.p8` key
6. I went to `Firebase`, clicked the `Gear Icon` > `Project Settings` > `Cloud Messaging` **(not Grow > Cloud Messaging like step 10)**
7. Under `iOS app configuration` > `APNs Authentication Key` I went to the first section `APNs Authentication Key` (NOT APNs Certificates), selected `Upload` and uploaded the `.p8` key, the `Key ID`, and my `Team Id`. The `teamId` is located in the `Membership` section and the keyId is the `xxxxxxx` part of the `xxxxxxx`.p8 file.
8. In my Xcode project I went to `Capabilities` > `Background Modes`, turned it `On`, and checked `Remote Notifications`
9. Then I went to > `Push Notifications` and turned it `On` which automatically generated an `Entitlement Certificate` for the app (it's inside the project navigator)
10. To send a notification in Firebase I went to `Grow` > `Cloud Messaging` > `Send Your First Message` > `1. Notification Text` entered some random String  > `2. Target` and selected my app's `bundleId` > `3. Scheduling Now` > 4. pressed Next > 5. selected `sound` and a `badge` > `Review`
11. In AppDelegate I added `import UserNotifications`, `import FirebaseMessaging`, `import Firebase`, registered for the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and added the code below.
12. To set up the [reCAPTCHA verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) I went to the `Blue Project Icon` > `Info` > `URL Types` then in the `URL Schemes` section (press the plus sign `+` if nothing is there), I entered in the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` from my `GoogleService-Info.plist`

I've added break points to all the print statements below and after I send a message from Firebase none of them get hit.

```
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
import Firebase

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge]) {
            [weak self] (granted, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                print("Success")
            }
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        } else {

            let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert, .sound, .badge]
            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        }
    }

    // MARK:- UNUserNotificationCenter Delegates
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.unknown)

        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count{
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }
        print("Registration Succeded! Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Notifcation Registration Failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if let gcm_message_id = userInfo["gcm_message_id"]{
            print("MessageID: \(gcm_message_id)")
        }

        print(userInfo)
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler(.alert)

        print("Handle push from foreground \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

        let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
        let d = dict["alert"] as! [String:Any]
        let title = d["title"] as! String
        let body = d["body"] as! String
        print("Title:\(title) + Body:\(body)")
        showFirebaseNotificationAlertFromAppDelegate(title: title, message: body, window: self.window!)
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        print("\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")

        if response.actionIdentifier == "yes"{
            print("True")
        }else{
            print("False")
        }
    }

    func showFirebaseNotificationAlertFromAppDelegate(title: String, message: String, window: UIWindow){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The message gets sent successfully as you can see in the below pic but I never receive it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should also add this to your code otherwise you won't be receiving the push notifications. Firebase needs to now what the apns token is to send you the pushes.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice. I’m not using that code you just added just now and I still get the notification. What does that do and why is it working without it?

Comment: Its working because you probaly have Method Swizzling enabled. When its enabled firebase automatically handles the apns token forwarding :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I haven’t added in the actual code yet but looking at what you wrote shouldn’t it be Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken? You put “= data”

Comment: I’ll upvote the answer after I add it in my project because that’s something that will easily get overlooked. I’ll do it in a couple of hours.

Comment: Hey what''s up,I just checked my code, I'm actually already using that. I forgot to c+p it in my question although my code is: Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.unknown). Is there a difference?

Comment: The enum MessagingAPNSTokenType has 3 options ( unknown, sandbox, prod). Sandbox is for testing (when you publish the app in test flight or Crashlytics) so when you use this type you won't be receiving any pushes from production. Prod as the name suggests (when you publish the app in the store) will receive incoming push notifications targeted for production. And if you set it to unknown then firebase will try to figure out which token you provided.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I upvoted you for such a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are missing some of the configuration for the FCM to work properly.

From what I see you aren't sending the token to firebase and you aren't registering for the FCM.

See the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client for more details.

To send the push message through the firebase you need to have the FCM token. The token you are using is the one coming from the APNS servers and you need to forward it to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I got the [answer from here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1339#issuecomment-399904389)

I was supposed to add `Messaging.messaging().delegate = self` BEFORE `FirebaseApp.configure()`

I also had to add in the Messaging Delegate to receive the FCM Registration Token.

Inside `didFinishLaunching` add `Messaging.messaging().delegate = self`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self // make sure this is added BEFORE FirebaseApp.Configure
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // all the other code inside didFinishLaunching goes here...
}

   // all the other methods from above goes here...
```

****Also at the bottom of the AppDelegate file add the Messaging Delegate and it's method. This is where the `FCM Token` is received:

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Your Firebase FCM Registration Token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
}
```